# Marklogic Spring Boot - Installing a Rest Endpoint

Tags: gradle, marklogic, marklogic-8

I am currently using the `Marklogic spring boot` demo. So far I have been able to add indexes, facets, front-end logic etc just fine.

Right now, I am trying to layer in some semantic logic into a rest endpoint.

I wrote a simple query into the query console, and attempted to add it to the `src/main/ext` folder so that it would get deployed by the `ml-gradle` `bootrun`.

Right now. This file will get deployed to the `test-modules` database, and is visible once saved (I can see it in explorer under URI `/ext/my-endpoint`. I also tried adding a folder named `rest-api` but that just adds it to `/ext/rest-api/my-endpoint`

At the top of the endpoint I have it declared as 
`module namespace ext = "http://marklogic.com/rest-api/resource/my-endpoint";

However when I navigate to the URL it should be living at  `http://localhost:8090/LATEST/resources/my-endpoint?`

It tells me it does not exist.

So I can see it in the modules database, but I can't use it on HTTP. the Query works in the query console (and is rather trivial, and-query of json-property-word-queries)

My question is:

How can I properly update the marklogic-spring-boot framework to properly deploy rest endpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured it out it seems.

Manually creating the file isn't registering the distribution workflow properly.

Instead I create the resource using `ml-gradle`

`gradle mlCreateResource -PresourceName=my_endpoint`

This will create a new folder called services, and create the endpoint for me, which can then have code over written.

Still not sure what gradle is doing special, so I can know what the proper way to do this manually would be, but at least it works.

Comment: Yes, you need to put it in `src/main/ml-modules/services/`, contents of that folder will be treated in a special way, not merely uploaded to the modules database like the contents of `src/main/ml-modules/ext/`. It is because REST extensions need to be installed with a special http call against the REST api: http://docs.marklogic.com/REST/PUT/v1/config/resources/[name]

Comment: Little more information on how ml-gradle loads the different kinds of modules that the Client REST API supports - https://github.com/marklogic-community/ml-gradle/wiki/How-modules-are-loaded